# How does this if statement work? It appears to have no boolean expression

Tags: arrays, if-statement, pseudocode

This is a snippet of code. I am unsure how the if statement on the second last line works? It doesn't have a boolean expression like 'if A[n − 1, j] == x' or anything like that. Could someone explain what it actually does to me? Thanks

```
Connected(A[0..n − 1, 0..n − 1])

  //Input: Adjacency matrix A[0..n − 1, 0..n − 1]) of an undirected graph G

  //Output: 1 (true) if G is connected and 0 (false) if it is not

if n = 1 return 1 //one-vertex graph is connected by definition

else

 if not Connected(A[0..n − 2, 0..n − 2]) return 0

 else for j ←0 to n − 2 do
          if A[n − 1, j] return 1
      return 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It calls for the A function which returns a boolean (0 or 1), so that's how it works.

Then, when your code executes `A[n − 1, j]`, it will call the A function, which is the function that you're defining there and it will (eventually) return your boolean

This is a recursive function. You'll see lots of them and finnally understand it. In fact, is simple, it is a function that calls itself many times, each one with different parameters, until one of the calls truly returns a result which is passed all the way back through all the chain of functions

Answer (score 0):

`if A[n−1, j] == 1` is equivalent to `if A[n-1,j]`

An adjancency matrix usually has ones & zeros, yes & no or true & false - just 2 possible values - essentially every element has (some kind of) boolean value indicating whether the 2 vertices are connected. Also, this being pseudocode, it doesn't have so much the function to 'work', but more to convey an algorithm in human readable (& simple) terms.

Answer (score 0):

It depends, since pseudocode isn't exactly rigorously defined, there are multiple possible meanings.

`if A[n-1,j]` can be equivalent (assuming a numeric type) to `if A[n-1,j] == 1` or to `if A[n-1,j] != 0` or (assuming a boolean type) to `if A[n-1,j] == true`.    For an adjacency matrix (consisting of binary true/false or 0/1 data) these possibilities may be equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm reduces the adjacency matrix down to a sub-graph of a single node (n = 1). After this base case, it determines whether or not you have a connected graph by checking for "holes" using a loop.

In this loop, you are checking to see if you have an "orphan node" (entire row is zeros in adjacency matrix).
Building from the single node up, you can forward-chain to see if the graph is connected.
**Note, in an undirected graph, as you check from your base case, you WILL find a disconnected node if the graph is not completely connected.** Even though it might be attached to another node--it will be attached to a node you haven't included yet in your search.

```js
 else
   for j← 0 to n− 2 do //we hit the base case, now forward-chain from single node
     if A[n− 1, j]//traverse the whole row (i.e. "is this node connected to anything else?")
     return 1 //there's a connection, we can return
     return 0 // if ALL zeros in adjacency matrix, you have an orphaned node
```

Hope that helps! :)

To clarify--the if statement is kind of ambiguous. To me, the algorithm is only complete if you check the ENTIRE row (the `j` indices) for ALL zeros. This is the case where you return false. If there's a single connection to a previous node, you can induct ("forward-chain") and continue your search.

Cheers,
-Gabe

P.S.
This is MUCH more easily read in nested for loops that check for a completely empty row.